# identityserver 4 get current user's access_token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, identityserver4

I am having trouble getting my current user's access_token. 
Here is my setup:

- QuickstartIdentityServer (QIS) in aspnet core, identity and EF storage
- API (API) in NodeJs. Validates jwt tokens in header against QIS.
- SPA angular app that works great with QIS and API and is out of the scope of this question

In a section of the QuickstartIdentityServer (QIS) site (user details page), I would like to call an API endpoint using an access_token to authenticate the request. I am struggling to retrieve the current user's access_token from my QIS site. Whenever I call `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` I get a null value. I have seen this section of IdSrv4 documentation: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html?highlight=gettokenasync but it seems to apply to an MVC client and not my own identity server.

Anyone could shed some light on how to get my user's access_token ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a starting point to try to explain better my issue:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity

Starting from this QIS project, I would like to get the logged in user's access token. So for instance, if I edit `HomeController` to add this call:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
     return View(accessToken);
}
```

I would then be able to call my NodeJS API with this token in the Auth Header.

Hope this explains better my issue.

Comment: Please provide some code how your IdentityServer is setup or which QIS you are using (github link?). Also where in the request chain are you trying to access the access_token? Eg. SPA calls API which returns a redirect to UserDetails page in QIS. Is this call in the Get or Post back? Providing some code will help us answer your question.

Comment: You may need to look into using delegation via extension grants.  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html.

Comment: Identity Server only issues `access_token` for a Client (not itself).  I believe it issues `id_token` for its own use but not sure if it's stored in the cookie.  You can check if it does by trying `var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");` in the QIS project.

Comment: You're right, it looks like I'll have to create a dedicated Client w/ ClientCredentials grant type. I would have liked to "impersonate" the current user for this call to API but I'll work around this issue with service to service auth. Thanks for your help. I'll post my solution as soon as I get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to authenticate myself w/ my API using a dedicated Client using client credentials grant and the following call to get an access_token:

```
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, clientId, clientSecret);
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scope);
```

Then I can add to my request header to API the access_token returned in `tokenResponse`:

```
        using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
          client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
          ...
          // execute request
        }
```

The downside is that I can't "impersonate" the current currently logged on IS on API side.

Comment: You are using the token and scope of a client in this example. Your original question was how to use the token of a user, which you would normally find in the claims I think.

var token = (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("access_token");